# Elmah style logging for .NET

Tags: .net, logging, web

Using Elmah for un-handled exceptions, but I'm also looking for Elmah style general purpose logger, something with a web front end that's friendly and easy to use.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm the founder of [elmah.io](https://elmah.io), which is a commercial service which runs on top of ELMAH as well as common logging frameworks like log4net, NLog and Serilog. You get a lot of the same information like ELMAH, when logging Information, Warning, Debug ... messages as well.

Comment: In Pricing, what does 'Message Limit' impose?

Comment: It's the maximum allowed number of messages per month. A message is an error, a message etc.

Comment: Thanks, a bit confusing in conjunction with 'Unlimited Logs'.

Comment: I think we'll switch from calling them logs to applications, since that's a common confusion :)

Comment: I think the pricing and imposed limits are a bit much. 2500 messages for $10 - comes out more expensive than an average SMS text message :P Google Analytics can be easily integrated into any .NET app - and there are no limits - not saying its the same thing, but limits of the packages are not realistic in my opinion for production applications. If I'm paying for a logging service I'd expect some ridiculous upper bound limits that I would never fill up. Rethink pricing model perhaps? :)

Comment: Like you say, you can't compare something like an error to a pixel request on Analytics. Also a text message is 160 characters. What you get here is all of the contextual information around why an error happened like: all cookies, all server variables, all form variables, etc. Storage costs money. With that said, I can tell you that we are working on a new storage architecture which will allow us to add more messages to each plan. But you won't ever see ridiculously high upper bounds, since that would be too expensive to fit inside $10 :)

Comment: Google Analytics does more than just pixel requests, you can also submit exceptions, events, log messages, etc. Additional storage and processing associated with exception handling is understood, however stand-alone Elmah can be used for that. It would be really great if we can have a very lightweight unlimited option for logging only w/o exception handling, just simple log messages for Info/Warnings/etc - perhaps this could be your "Express" or "Free" offering, you'd get a lot more dev exposure with a Freemium model. In any case, great product! Looking forward to new pricing :)

Comment: Thank you for the kind words and the input. Really appreciate it. You can't compete with Googles free services. But unlike Google, we don't use your data for anything fishy. We tried a freemium model and we had a lot more exposure, but also spend a lot of time bugging people to purchase the paid product. We switched to a trial based model and it feels a lot better. Hope to see you when we put more messages in each plan.